# Получение данных с веб-сервера

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Как можно получить данные с веб сервера, используя Forismatic Api.
Как описывают сами авторы: http://ru.forismatic.com/api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чем их пример не устраивает?

```
Пример запроса:
POST:
method=getQuote&key=457653&format=xml&lang=ru

ответ:
<forismatic>
<quote>
<quoteText>Краткость — сестра таланта</quoteText>
<quoteAuthor></quoteAuthor>
<senderName>имя или ник кто прислал цитату</senderName>
<senderLink>email или адрес сайта того кто прислал</senderLink>
</quote>
</forismatic>
```

Вообще то там все написано, что и как, а на каком языке отправлять запрос это дело каждого.
hiden замени на нужные тебе.

```
<form action="http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0">
POST:
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="getQuote">
<input type="hidden"  name="key" value="457653">
<input type="hidden" name="format"  value="xml">
<input type="hidden" name="lang"  value="ru">
</form>
```

Comment: Не понятно на каком языке это реализовывать =)
Пожалуйста, можете показать реализацию в виде html-форм ?